# How much can be developed the low pecs of chest

Tags: weightlifting, chest

i have visible low pecs but i don't know if i ended on that spot or i can develop it much more.My question concluded the previous sentence is how much can be developed the low pecs of chest?I think it can't be more "visible" more "down" or more "out".Have a limit those?No drugs,only workouts and proper intake foods meals.I want to ask the "distance" it can be obtained the low pecs.How much can it "grow"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

As you can see the pectoral major doesn't have much growth potential sideways as it is limited by it's attachment points to the arm, but there's really nothing limiting the forward growth of the pectoral that give it the thickness from sideways, well nothing except the natural ''physiological'' limitation of cellular growth.

No drug can alter the natural limit of muscle growth(which is equal for everyone), when a muscle cell becomes too big it dies out. But even then there is no evidence than any human has ever reached a limit in muscular growth.

Answer (score 0):

For 'lower' pec work, do decline bench, dips and cable crosses with active mind muscle connection and heavy weights. 3 times a week setting two days for volume (lighter weight more reps) and another for heavy weight. Hit that with daily 8 hours of sleep as well as sufficient protein/nutrients. If you're at a good body weight right now, I might even go for a 3 month slow bulk to optimize growth.

Comment: I am not asking how to grow the lower pec,but I ask how much this muscle can be increased,the limit it has of growth

Comment: That's a pretty subjective question and i'm not sure tbh, it depends on the person, their age, diet, sleep etc. Way too many factors for me to make a broad statement.

Comment: Indeed,but it can't be length ,example more than 0.40 cm. Do you understand? Even in the best age it needs the chest can reach the full potential,diet ,sleep etc the chest low pec can't be so much bigger it has a limit.